# Need help on using documentdb-lumenize on .net documentdb client sdk

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-.net, lumenize

I have a problem using the aggregate storedproc lumenize https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize with the .net client. I get error when try passing in the parameter and query into the storedproc. Below is my code

```
 public async static void QuerySP()        {
            using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
            {
                //Get the Database
                var database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == databaseId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

                //Get the Document Collection
                var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == collectionId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

                StoredProcedure storedProc = client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.StoredProceduresLink).Where(sp => sp.Id == "cube").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();             


                dynamic result =  await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(storedProc.SelfLink, "{cubeConfig: {groupBy: 'publication', field: 'pid', f: 'count'}, filterQuery: 'SELECT pid, publication FROM c'}");
                Console.WriteLine("Result from script: {0}\r\n", result.Response);
            }
}
```

I am getting the following error when execute the code

> Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: cubeConfig or savedCube required\r\nStack trace: Error: cubeConfig or savedCube required\n   at fn (cube.js:1803:7)\n   at __docDbMain (cube.js:1844:5)\n   at Unknown script code (cube.js:1:2)"]}

Not sure what I had done wrong. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is that the config is being sent as a string. I'm not a .NET developer but I do have a Windows VM and will try to your code and get back to you. In the mean time, if you know how to create plain objects, try that and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. The problem is that you are sending in the cubeConfig as a string. It needs to be an object. Here is code that does that:

```
string cubeConfigString = @"{
    cubeConfig: {
        groupBy: 'publication', 
        field: 'pid', 
        f: 'count'
    }, 
    filterQuery: 'SELECT * FROM c'
}";

Object cubeConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(cubeConfigString);
Console.WriteLine(cubeConfig);

dynamic result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>("dbs/dev-test-database/colls/dev-test-collection/sprocs/cube", cubeConfig);

Console.WriteLine(result.Response);
```

Comment: BTW, I loaded the cube sproc manually using the Azure console app. Do you have code that reads from a file and loads the string in that file as a sproc? If so, I'd love to see it. Also, my email is larry @at@ maccherone .dot. com, to send code or if you have other questions. I'll send you my Skype and/or phone number if you email me there. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for your help. The above code is working well. For the sproc, I had early save the sproc into documentdb, so I just use the above code to retrieve the sproc. I do know the Microsoft example load the file and upload and save the sproc into documentdb https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/ServerSideScripts/Program.cs

Comment: I have another question. When I using the code, it generated the continuation, do I need to do a while loop until continuation=null and sum up all the count? And for continuation, do I just append into the original cubeConfig as following?
string cubeConfigString = @"{
    cubeConfig: {
        groupBy: 'publication', 
        field: 'pid', 
        f: 'count'
    }, 
    filterQuery: 'SELECT * FROM c', continuation: 'xxxxxxx'
}";

Thanks.

Comment: No. The OLAP cube is designed to return its last completed state to the client. If you simply send back the JSON that the execution of the cube sproc sent to you as the parameter for another executeStoredProcedure call, it'll pick up right where it left off using the continuation information. Pretty neat, huh? I want to upgrade it so it serializes to a temporary document or attachment on the server so you don't need to ship the entire state back and forth. Let me know if that's something that would strongly desire.

Comment: When I said JSON above, I meant to send the dynamic Object that is returned from the SDK call. Not sure if it matters if it's a string, but I know it works if it's a dynamic Object.

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for the reply. I still not understanding what you mean about that. Can you give me a sample how should i pass back for subsequent call if I notice there is a continuation in the return? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for your help. I manage to get the code working. I have post my version of code in below.

Comment: Ugh. Could have saved me an hour. :-) Anyway, I just now finished updating my example to show executing until no continuation: https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize/blob/master/DocumentDB-Lumenize.cs

Answer (score 1):

my working code

```
public async static Task QuerySP2()
    {
        using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
        {
            //Get the Database
            var database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == databaseId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

            //Get the Document Collection
            var collection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == collectionId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

            StoredProcedure storedProc = client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collection.StoredProceduresLink).Where(sp => sp.Id == "cube").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

            string filterQuery = string.Format(@"SELECT * from c");

            string cubeConfigString = @"{
                cubeConfig: {
                    groupBy: 'publication', 
                    field: 'id', 
                    f: 'count'
                }, 
                filterQuery: '" + filterQuery + "'}";

            dynamic cubeConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(cubeConfigString);
            Console.WriteLine(cubeConfig);

            string continuationToken = null;

            dynamic result=null;
            do
            {


                var queryDone = false;
                while (!queryDone)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<dynamic>(storedProc.SelfLink, cubeConfig);
                        cubeConfig = result.Response;
                        continuationToken = cubeConfig.continuation;
                        queryDone = true;
                    }
                    catch (DocumentClientException documentClientException)
                    {
                        var statusCode = (int)documentClientException.StatusCode;
                        if (statusCode == 429 || statusCode == 503)
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(documentClientException.RetryAfter);
                        else
                            throw;
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
                    {
                        if (aggregateException.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(DocumentClientException))
                        {

                            var docExcep = aggregateException.InnerException as DocumentClientException;
                            var statusCode = (int)docExcep.StatusCode;
                            if (statusCode == 429 || statusCode == 503)
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(docExcep.RetryAfter);
                            else
                                throw;
                        }
                    }
                }



            } while (continuationToken != null);

            Console.WriteLine("Result from script: {0}\r\n", result.Response);


        }


    }
```

Comment: Cool. Out of curiosity (from a .NET noob), is it OK to have async code within a while loop? My solution uses recursion but that style preference may just be from my node.js background.

Comment: Also, I didn't know that 503 errors were possible. Where do you see that in the docs?

Comment: BTW, I borrowed you 429 retry code and updated my example on GitHub. Thanks for that.

Comment: I copy from the solution here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8edaa6bf-a141-4363-b280-0964d0525129/request-rate-is-too-large-azure-document-db?forum=AzureDocumentDB